# Get characters before first space

Tags: r, regex, substring

I am looking for a grep way to obtain the characters in a string prior to the first space.

I have hacked the following function, as i could not figure out how to do it using the `grep` type commands in `R`.

Could someone help with the `grep` solution - if there is one ...

```
beforeSpace <- function(inWords) {
    vapply(inWords, function(L) strsplit(L, "[[:space:]]")[[1]][1], FUN.VALUE = 'character')
}
words <- c("the quick", "brown dogs were", "lazier than quick foxes")
beforeSpace(words)

R>          the quick         brown dogs were lazier than quick foxes 
              "the"                 "brown"                "lazier"
```

And do let me know if there's a better way than `grep` (or my function, `beforeSpace`) to do this.

Comment: Why a grep solution?

Comment: grep is not a must ... Just figured it would be the natural way.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Or just `sub`, with credit to @flodel:

```
sub(" .*", "", words)
# and if the 'space' can also be a tab or other white-space:
sub("\\s.*","",words)
#[1] "the"    "brown"  "lazier"
```

Comment: Any non-breaking spaces would first have to be dealt with using something like `gsub('\u00A0',' ',words)`

Answer (score 5):

You can use `qdap`'s `beg2char` (beginning of the string to a particular character) as follows:

```
x <- c("the quick", "brown dogs were", "lazier than quick foxes")
library(qdap)
beg2char(x)
## [1] "the"    "brown"  "lazier"
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `stringi`

```
library(stringi) 
stri_extract_first(words, regex="\\w+")
#[1] "the"    "brown"  "lazier"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `stringr`-package from `tidyverse` with `regex()`

```
words %>% str_extract(regex('^\\S*'))
# [1] "the"    "brown"  "lazier"
```

deconstructing the regex:

- `^` means start matching at the start of the line.
- `\S` matches any non-whitespace character (oposite of `\s`). We use an extra escape backslash here for [this reason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54396380/12785645), so it becomes `\\S`
- `*` matches the previous pattern 0 to unlimited times. This means that we continue to look for more non-whitespace characters until we found a whitespace.