# Why four backslashes in the regular expression?

Tags: regex

`"^\\\\d{1,2}$"`

I have the above regex. I know that the string parser will remove two backlashes leaving us with `\\d`. Taking one for the meta-character, what is the function of the extraneous `\` ? I haven't had previous experience in regex. Or is the string pattern is in itself [backslash][integer up to two occurences]. Am I missing something ?

Comment: @Tiw JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

Backslashes escape other backslashes, as well as special characters.

What you have there is:

- `\d` is "digit", in your regex engine.
- `\\d` is backslash-escaping-backslash + d, == \d, in your string quoting mechanism.
- `\\\\d` is backslash-escaping-backslash, twice, +d, probably escaping the command line if you're using a shell, or if you have to pass the string through `system` or `rsh` or something.

Answer (score 1):

There need to escape the `\` so that your string literal can express it as data before you transform it into a regular expression.

First `^\\` means pattern start with `\` and `\\d{1,2}` means digit(\d) should be occur 1 to 2 times. That's why there four back-slash.

Match case:

```
\12
\1
.......
```