# Delete after the space

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have this dataset I need to delete (Delete and Trash) everything after the name city. How can I do?

```
dati1<- c("a - Novara Delete", "b - Torino Trash", "c - Milano", "f - Bari")
    
dati2 <-data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(dati1, split = " - ")))
```

I have tried:

```
c <- dati2$X2 %>%  mutate(dati2$X2 = sub("\\s+[^ ]+$", "", dati2$X2))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get characters before first space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25477920/get-characters-before-first-space)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `separate`:

```r
tidyr::separate(data.frame(dati1), col = dati1, into = stringr::str_c("col", 1:2), extra = 'drop')

  col1   col2
1    a Novara
2    b Torino
3    c Milano
4    f   Bari
```

or with base R

```r
data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(strsplit(dati1, split = "[^[:alnum:]]+"), head, 2)))
```

Comment: I have this: Error in str_c("col", 1:2) : could not find function "str_c"

Comment: See edit. str_c is from package stringr

Answer (score 0):

An option with `read.table` from `base R`

```
read.table(text = sub("^(\\S+ - \\S+)\\s+.*", "\\1", dati1),
     header = FALSE, sep = "-", strip.white = TRUE)
   V1     V2
1  a Novara
2  b Torino
3  c Milano
4  f   Bari
```